# Writing File To External Storage in Android 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android

Hello guys I want to download and put a file in public folder on the sdcard of the mobile so that the user can directly access it. Prior to android 4.4 it was easy but now android is not allowing me to create a folder or file on the sdcard.
Please Help....

Comment: That's correct. Use an external files dir. Is an Android/data directory created -by the OS- on the card? Is there a public folder on the card? What's it's path?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a call getExternalFilesDirs(null) from your activity to get absolute paths to internal/external folders related to your application.