# how to move a file from internal sd card to external sd card, which is read only (restricted since 4.4)

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard

I already asked similar things in the past, but I still don't get it and I am not sure if meanwhile the techinic has changed. I also didn't find any similar answer here, so sorry when I probably ask something already discussed.

I simply want to move a file from my internal sd-card to external sd-card by code. I know I can't just use `File.copy`, which would be simple, because of write-restrictions since Android 4.4.

What is the approach for doing this? Is there still interaction needed from the user? Is there probably a sample out in the world, how to do this?

kind regards

Comment: Yo can not copy & after delete source file?

Comment: The problem is, that I do not have write access to the external sd card . Or do you have without root ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513004/android-kitkat-sdcard-write-permission or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890706/writing-file-to-external-storage-in-android-4-4-kitkat